# How can I retrieve the description of a Git branch?

Tags: git

Git supports branch descriptions. They can be edited with `git branch --edit-description`.

How can I retrieve that description from the command line for consumption by other shell utilities?

One way to do this is to temporarily set `$EDITOR` (or core.editor) to `cat` or an equivalent before calling `git branch --edit-description`, but it is somewhat invasive, and it returns several comment lines that I would prefer to do without (even though filtering them would be an option if there is no better way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git config --get-all branch.$branch.description
```

Comment: That works, I'll accept once Stack Overflow lets me.